# Shim XmlNode parent node returning null instead of expected shim result

Tags: microsoft-fakes

With the following use of Shims from my test:

```
var testParentNode = new ShimXmlNode(xNode);
var singleNode = new ShimXmlNode(xDoc);
singleNode.ParentNodeGet = () => testParentNode;
ShimXmlNode.AllInstances.SelectSingleNodeString = (instance, x) => singleNode
```

I would expect that when the code following Code is called:

```
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("blah...");
var parentNode = node.ParentNode;
```

that parentNode would be equal to the testParentNode, but instead it is null. The node returned from SelectSingleNode however is as expected.

Why is this?

Comment: A solution to our problem was to create an actual xml node using xml.linq with the required depth. This then replaced singleNode in the test code. This means XmlNode in the production code is actually doing the work instead of just returning a faked result.  Which is not really what I was looking for. (now I'm testing 2 things, that I can create a valid xml node in my test and that the flow is as expected)

Answer (score 0):

Fakes has two types of Fakes. Stubs and Shims.

You are using the very last shim correctly. It overrides all calls to the XmlNode class' SelectSingleNode method at runtime.

Normally, for the other part you'd use stubs, because they are simply an instance that calls delegates instead of the base methods. This, however, only works if things are virtual.

In your case, you should probably shim all instances of ParentNode's get.

Comment: We tried the AllInstances option and it still output a null.  Although we could not Stub XmlNode, we could Stub XmlDocument, which derives from XmlNode, but setting the shim to return the stub also returned null.

Comment: So you created a valid XmlNode, and did `ShimXmlNode.AllInstances.ParentNodeGet = () => whateverYouNamedIt;`? I can't imagine how that could return null. What doesn't make sense to me is why you need to do this at all. Your XML parsing shouldn't be so deep in your architecture that you have to shim it like this. You should be passing something into a method and asserting a result. The XML method should return something useful, not more XmlNodes. Are you trying to test Fakes itself?